# i have wifi problem with my ubuntu suddenly

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Apr 2016 01:48 EET +0200

Booted last: 23 Apr 2016 01:19 EET +0200

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3803]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 03f0:0a01 Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 2400c
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 001 Device 041: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 04d8:0033 Microchip Technology, Inc. PICkit2
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 062a:0201 Creative Labs Defender Office Keyboard (K7310) S Zodiak KM-9010
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5722 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6369280  0 
cfg80211              532480  1 wl

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41660 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25930 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52930522 (52.9 MB)  TX bytes:2528732 (2.5 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       746     1  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.5
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ahmed]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ahmed | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Ahmed | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Cairo (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     3F8570547EE3A2BA3D5D734
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        DE:B3:43:0A:26:E6:7D:3D:3B:54:B9:DD:13:25:B3:3A:46:B2:F2:DD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b2 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  773.947830] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[  773.947882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1182.244519] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1182.244568] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1368.171020] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 1368.171040] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1605.469497] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[ 1641.489279] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[ 1641.489358] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1643.090631] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 1643.090646] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

i have problem i cant connect via my wifi suddenly , so any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

solve all the problem